# Depend on DLL without header file, worked in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, dll, c++-cli

I have a legacy project that used to be build in Visual C++ 2005 Express, and it depends on a certain third party DLL. As far as I can tell it doesn't come with a lib or header file.

The project compiles fine in Visual C++ 2005, here is a screenshot showing the DLL visible and browsable in the object explorer. The code can also use it without `#include` or anything like that, which is pretty weird.

[image: 2005 original]

Importing the project into Visual Studio 2019 works as well, the code can still use the DLL and it is listed under both the dependencies and the references:

[image: 2019 imported]

I now want to achieve the same thing in a new project, but I cannot figure out how to register the DLL as a dependency. Things I found online and tried:

- *"Just include the header or lib file"* doesn't work, I don't have one
- [LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31710797/5517612) are awfully contrived and don't seem necessary because it's clearly possible without.
- [Create your own lib file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127548/5517612) doesn't work either, `dumpbin` doesn't show any symbols for my DLL: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbszP.png)

How do I register the DLL as a dependency? And where does Visual C++ 2005 get the list of methods in the DLL from is the first place?

Comment: Perhaps it is a c++-cli or C# library? Note that dlls never participate in C++ build process and there is no way to make it a dependency.

Comment: The best thing in life now is to read a book or a couple of tutorials on the differences between managed and unmanaged code before starting working on a business project right away.

Comment: @VTT Looks like it's c++-cli indeed, there is `gcnew` in the source code. How do I use a library like that?

Comment: Perhaps you need to create a C++-cli project first.

Comment: @VTT Everything works now, if you post your observation that it's a C++/CLI library I'll accept that as an answer.